# Optimizing date queries in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, indexing, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-performance

I'm having a hard time to optimizing queries on a very big table. Basically all of the them filter the set of results by the date:

```
SELECT FROM bigtable WHERE date >= '2015-01-01' AND date <= '2016-01-01' ORDER BY date desc;
```

Adding the following date index actually makes things worse:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY bigtable_date_index ON bigtable(date(date));
```

That is, without the index it takes about 1s to run and with it it takes about 10s to run. But with bigger ranges and filtering it is very slow even without that index.

I'm using postgresql 9.4 and I see that 9.5 has some improvements for sorting that might help?

Does BRIN indexes should help in this case?

Comment: Please read http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions then [edit] your question and add the missing information.

Comment: And a strong advice to **not** name your columns `date`.

Comment: this is obviously and example @joop

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, will add some more info

Answer (score 0):

For an index to be effective, it needs to index the same thing you're filtering by. In this case, you're filtering by `date`, but you appears to have indexed `date(date)`, so the index can't be used.

Either filter your table using `date(date)`:

```
SELECT FROM bigtable
WHERE date(date) >= '2015-01-01' AND date(date) <= '2016-01-01'
ORDER BY date(date) desc;
```

Or index the naked `date`:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY bigtable_date_index ON bigtable(date);
```